# Will the weight initialize again when next batch come in?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
def weight_variable(shape, l2_reg_lambda=None, l1_reg_lambda=None):
  regularizer = None
  if l2_reg_lambda:
      regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(l2_reg_lambda)
  elif l1_reg_lambda:
      regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l1_regularizer(l1_reg_lambda)
  return tf.get_variable('weight', shape, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1), regularizer=regularizer)


def bias_variable(shape):
  return tf.get_variable('bias', shape, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1))


def full_connect(inputs, num_units, activation=None, name='full_connect'):
  with tf.variable_scope(name):
    shape = [inputs.get_shape()[-1], num_units]
    weight = weight_variable(shape)
    bias = bias_variable(shape[-1])
    outputs = tf.matmul(inputs, weight) + bias
    if activation=="relu":
      outputs = tf.nn.relu(outputs)
    elif activation == "tanh":
      outputs = tf.tanh(outputs)
    elif activation == "sigmoid":
      outputs = tf.nn.sigmoid(outputs)
    return outputs
```

This is my full connect layer. And I use it in the graph like this.

```
nn_layers.full_connect_(self.wide_deep_embed, config.num_classes, activation='sigmoid', name='output_layer')
```

Will the weight, initialized in the weight_variable, initialize again when next batch data come in ? Or just initialize from the random normal distribution only at the first time ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables initialization has nothing in common with input data.

Your variables are allocated and initialized once the graph has been built. After that, the graph is static and won't change. The initialization is done just once.

Comment: The variable initialization step has to be explicit, though.

Answer (score 0):

Variable values exist only in the session ( tf.Session() ), not on graph. As long as session is maintained between batches, weights will not be reinitialized.

As E_net4 commented, explicit initialization is needed within the session.